# Where/when does the object impedence mismatch occur?

Tags: database, orm

When people talk about object impedence mismatch, where does the mismatch happen? What can't a database interpret from an object model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually because Objects can inherit methods and properties from other Objects and in a relationship database there is no equivalent.

See the following for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference is that databases / relational model are based on sets (rows) of data that are globally available, whereas object-oriented models are based on trees of encapsulated, or hidden (not globally available) data.  The two approaches are philosophically at odds - one exposes all (clumped into tables, organized by traits), the other hides all (clumped into nodes, organized by things).  To go from relational to object-oriented, global trait data in rows have to be split up and hidden in things.  To go from object-oriented to relational, hidden thing data in objects have to be collected into rows and exposed.  This can be a lot of work, and there are many different ways to approach it, depending on your situation.